# How can I pick a set of vertices to subtract from a polygon such that the distortion is minimum?

Tags: algorithm, polygon

I'm working with a really slow renderer, and I need to approximate polygons so that they look almost the same when confined to a screen area containing very few pixels. That is, I'd need an algorithm to go through a polygon and subtract/move a bunch of vertices until the end polygon has a good combination of shape preservation and economy of vertice usage.

I don't know if there's a formal name for these kind of problems, but if anyone knows what it is it would help me get started with my research.

My untested plan is to remove the vertices that change the polygon area the least, and protect the vertices that touch the bounding box from removal, until the difference in area from the original polygon to the proposed approximate one exceeds a tolerance I specify.

This would all be done only once, not in real time.

Any other ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: How is the polygon defined? Also what have you tried?

Comment: They're UTM polygons that define an area on earth. They may contain up to 100 vertices, but some of them (not all) are basically rectangular so you could reduce those to 4 points for instance.

Comment: I define the polygon with an x,y point in an ordered list.

Comment: Also, haven't tried my own plan yet. I can go ahead with it and see what happens i suppose. I have nightmares of the polygon morphing to something of similar area but an unrecognizable shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried my own plan first: Protect the vertices touching the bounding box, then remove the rest in the order that changes the resultant area the least, until  you can't find a vertice to remove that keeps the new polygon area within X% of the original one. This is the result with X = 5%:

[image]

When the user zooms out really far these shapes fit the bill well enough for me. I haven't tried any of the other suggestions. The savings are quite astonishing, sometimes from 80-100 vertices down to 4 or 5.

Answer (score 2):

You're thinking about the problem in a slightly off way. If your goal is to reduce the number of vertices with a minimum of distortion, you should be defining your distortion in terms of those same vertices, which define the shape. There's a very simple solution here, which I believe would solve your problem:

1. Calculate distance between adjacent vertices
2. Choose a tolerance between vertices, below which the vertices are resolved into a single vertex
3. Replace all pairs of vertices with distances lower than your cutoff with a single vertex halfway between the two.
4. Repeat until no vertices are removed.

Since your area is ultimately decided by the vertex placement, this method preserves shape and minimizes shape distortion. The one drawback is that distance between vertices might be slightly less intuitive than polygon area, but the two are proportional. If you really wish, you could run through the change in area that would result from vertex removal, but that's a lot more work for questionable benefit imo.

As mentioned by Angus, if you want a direct solution for the change in area, it's not actually super difficult. Was originally going to leave this as an exercise to the reader, but it's totally possible to solve this exactly, though you need to include vertices on either side.

1. Assume you're looking at a window of vertices [A, B, C, D] that are connected in that order. In this example we're determining the "cost" of combining `B` and `C`.
2. Calculate the angle offset from collinearity from A toward C. Basically you just want to see how far from collinear the two points are. This is `|sin(|arctan(B - A)| - |arctan(C - A)|)|` Where pipes are absolute value, and differences are the sensical notion of difference.
3. Calculate the total distance over which the angle change will effectively be applied, this is just the euclidean distance from A to B times the euclidean distance from B to C.
4. Multiply the terms from 2 and 3 to get your first term
5. To get your second term, repeat steps 2 - 4 replacing A with D, B with C, and C with B (just going in the opposite direction)
6. Calculate the geometric mean of the two terms obtained.

The number that results in step 6 presents the full-picture minus a couple constants.

Comment: thanks, i'll give this a try. I wasn't too confident about my area algorithm.

Comment: @IBC Let me know if you have any questions, or if some simple python code would be helpful.

Comment: This is enough for me to get started. I can stand on my own two feet from here.

Comment: I suggest that removing vertices that are closest in distance may not always give you the best solution. For example, vertices around a tight curve are relatively more important to shape than vertices that are nearly collinear. A better algorithm might give extra weighting to preserving vertices with relatively smaller angles to adjacent vertices.

Comment: Thanks Angus I'll take that into account. I don't think i'll get to work on this till tomorrow though.

Comment: @AngusJohnson Wasn't thinking that far down the line, but I'll add a good distance metric to the answer that accounts for that.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus My own idea turned out really well. I'll try to implement yours when I'm bored and compare.